# Can 4 file descriptors point to the same file table entry

Tags: unix

The following sequence of code has been observed in various programs:

```
dup2(fd, 0);
dup2(fd, 1);
dup2(fd, 2);

if(fd > 2)
 close(fd);
```

I do not understand why the if test is needed. Suppose fd is 3, then we just have 4 file descriptor 0, 1,2,3 point the same entry in the file table. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

> *I do not understand why the if test is needed. Suppose fd is 3, then we just have 4 file descriptor 0, 1,2,3 point the same entry in the file table. Is this a problem?*

Suppose `fd` is 0, 1, or 2.  Without the test, one of STDIN, STDOUT, or STDERR will be closed.  This code is trying to ensure that IN/OUT/ERR are mapped to a known file — probably a redirect to `/dev/null` opened O_RDWR — so that later reads/writes aren't frustrated (EBADF) or, worse, sent to the "wrong" fd.

Or suppose the `close` is omitted entirely.  If `fd` is 3 or greater, then that file descriptor may leak to (be inherited by) child processes, even if IN/OUT/ERR are dup'd away before the exec, granting access to a resource we don't want the child to have.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose fd is 3, then we just have 4 file descriptor 0, 1,2,3 point the same entry in the file table. Is this a problem?

Maybe.

Since the standard streams point to the open file, it's probably OK to leak a file descriptor, since the underlying file description presumably won't be closed until process shutdown anyway.  It's *sloppy*, sure, but it's not actually going to cause an issue.

But that's a bit optimistic.  Maybe the program is going to call `fork()` and/or `exec()`, or maybe it will redirect the standard streams again.  In this case, we're not just leaking a file descriptor but a whole open file.  This is a Bad Thing.